# Ways to Detect whether AngularJS is loaded in the current page or not

Tags: angularjs

How can I detect whether AngularJS is loaded in the current page or not.  I want to load AngularJS from CDN and in case if it fails I want to load from LocalServer.  The following script does that for JQuery

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="libs/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Is there a similiar way for AngularJS.

Answer (score 14):

You could try testing for `window.angular`.

Comment: The following doesn't work, because (typeof window.angular) is an object: if (typeof window.angular === "undefined") { ... } Due to this trying to use only *window.angular* is not quite correct.