# Angular2 - how to call component function from outside the app

Tags: angular

I am using a javascript Object that has a callback. Once the callback is fired I want to call a function inside an Angular2 component.

example
HTML file.

```ts
    var run = new Hello('callbackfunction');

    function callbackfunction(){   
     // how to call the function **runThisFunctionFromOutside**
   }
   <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript', 
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
        packages: {'js/app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}} 
      });
      System.import('js/app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

My **App.component.ts**

```ts
import {Component NgZone} from 'angular2/core';
import {GameButtonsComponent} from './buttons/game-buttons.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: ' blblb'
})
export class AppComponent {

constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone){}

ngOnInit(){
    calledFromOutside() {
        this._ngZone.run(() => {
          this.runThisFunctionFromOutside();
    });
  }
  }
runThisFunctionFromOutside(){
   console.log("run");
}
```

How can i call the function **runThisFunctionFromOutside** which is inside App.component.ts

Comment: Could you give us more context? Where do you `run` object take place? How your callback is called? Thanks!

Comment: run is called in the html, outside <my-app></my-app>.

Comment: Okay. And the callback?

Comment: looks like you just need to use a closure to access the component within a callback, `ngOnInit(){
let vm = this;
    calledFromOutside() {
        vm._ngZone.run(() => {
          vm.runThisFunctionFromOutside();
    });
  }
  }

Answer (score 65, accepted):

See also [How do expose angular 2 methods publicly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276291/how-do-expose-angular-2-methods-publicly/35276652?noredirect=1#comment58266532_35276652)

When the component is constucted make it assign itself to a global variable. Then you can reference it from there and call methods.
Don't forget to use `zone.run(() => { ... })` so Angular gets notified about required change detection runs.

```ts
 function callbackfunction(){   
   // window['angularComponentRef'] might not yet be set here though
   window['angularComponent'].zone.run(() => {
     runThisFunctionFromOutside(); 
   });
 }

constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone){
  window['angularComponentRef'] = {component: this, zone: _ngZone};
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  window.angularComponent = null;
}
```

[**Plunker example1**](https://plnkr.co/edit/6gv2MbT4yzUhVUfv5u1b?p=preview)

In the browser console you have to switch from `<topframe>` to `plunkerPreviewTarget....` because Plunker executes the code in an `iFrame`.  Then run

```ts
window['angularComponentRef'].zone.run(() => {window['angularComponentRef'].component.callFromOutside('1');})
```

or

```ts
window.angularComponentRef.zone.run(() => {window.angularComponentRef.componentFn('2');})
```

**An alternative approach**

would be to dispatch events outside Angular and listen to them in Angular like explained in [Angular 2 - communication of typescript functions with external js libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997625/angular-2-communication-of-typescript-functions-with-external-js-libraries/36997723#36997723)

[**Plunker example2**](https://plnkr.co/edit/e77JkHmO7n5FYoKSXnIL?p=preview) (from the comments)

Comment: Out of interest, wouldn't it be better to inject the `Window` provider rather than attaching it directly to the `window` object?

Comment: Probably. But at first it should work at all I guess.

Comment: If minification changes the names it might be better to assign a function reference instead of a class reference (`window.angularComponentRef = {zone: zone, /*component: this*/ componentFn: this.callFromOutside};`).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer did you look at  question. I have the same issue. When i call a function, callFromOutside(){ 
      this.edit();
    } i get undefined

Comment: @Roninio not sure what you mean. Can you demonstrate it with a Plunker?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer https://plnkr.co/edit/rKZaWsjxZusitnDq1d3Z?p=preview in the console. window.angularComponentRef.zone.run(() => {
      window.angularComponentRef.component.callFromOutside('1');}
      ) i placed, version 16

Comment: check the `outside` button in `index.html` https://plnkr.co/edit/e77JkHmO7n5FYoKSXnIL?p=preview

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I manage to make it work using an extra `.bind(this)` So it will look like this: `window.ServiceName = { fname: this.fname.bind(this), zone: _ngZone };`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks for the response. The issue I had, was calling a function inside a child. I had to make in each constructor the NgZone event.

Comment: Once upgraded to RC4, window.angularComponentRef is throwing error, `Property 'angularComponentRef' does not exist on type 'Window'.`while starting the npm. Is there any alternative method to replace window.angularComponentRef

Comment: Please provide a Plunker.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I followed this steps but getting this problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849369/linkedin-with-angular-2

Comment: I can confirm that setting `window.angularComponent[Ref]` inside the component will not compile with latest setup. However using `window['angularComponentRef']` will do just fine. This answer is excellent, thanks for your contributions günter

Comment: Works great, but the app's performance is hurt. Something familiar with the problem?

Comment: @Harry I doubt this is related to performance. Perhaps you niid to invoke change detection to make Angular update bindings.

Answer (score 80):

I basically followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35297044/1015595), but I didn't want my "outside" code to know anything about NgZone. This is app.component.ts:

```
import {Component, NgZone, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    window.my = window.my || {};
    window.my.namespace = window.my.namespace || {};
    window.my.namespace.publicFunc = this.publicFunc.bind(this);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    window.my.namespace.publicFunc = null;
  }

  publicFunc() {
    this.ngZone.run(() => this.privateFunc());
  }

  privateFunc() {
    // do private stuff
  }
}
```

I also had to add a definition for TypeScript to extend the window object. I put this in typings.d.ts:

```
interface Window { my: any; }
```

Calling the function from the console is now as simple as:

```
my.namespace.publicFunc()
```

Comment: this works for me but publicFunc is always called twice?

Comment: this is more cleaner code, it worked for me, thanks!

Comment: This is an excellent solution and works. I think should be voted as the accepted answer.

Comment: Don't have to create the `Window interface`, you can keep it dynamic by using the `<any>` like `(<any>window).my = (<any>window).my || {};`

Answer (score 6):

Below is a solution.

```
function callbackfunction(){   
   window.angularComponent.runThisFunctionFromOutside();
}
       <script>
          System.config({
            transpiler: 'typescript', 
            typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
            packages: {'js/app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}} 
          });
          System.import('js/app/main')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
        </script>
```

My App.component.ts

```
import {Component NgZone} from 'angular2/core';
import {GameButtonsComponent} from './buttons/game-buttons.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
       template: ' blblb'
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone){
  window.angularComponent = {runThisFunctionFromOutside: this.runThisFunctionFromOutside, zone: _ngZone};
}


    runThisFunctionFromOutside(){
      console.log("run");
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I access variable which is defined in AppComponent, through runThisFunctionFromOutside function?

Comment: @Starwave: You need to bind the component context to the callback function: "runThisFunctionFromOutside: this.runThisFunctionFromOutside.bind(this)"

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thank you

Comment: Error property 'angularComponent ' does not exist on type 'Window

Comment: @codemirror (<any>window).angularComponent = {runThisFunctionFromOutside: this.runThisFunctionFromOutside, zone: _ngZone};

Answer (score 3):

An other approach without using global variables is to use pass a control object and bind its properties to the variables and methods to expose.

```js
export class MyComponentToControlFromOutside implements OnChanges {

  @Input() // object to bind to internal methods
  control: {
    openDialog,
    closeDialog
  };

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.control) {
      // bind control methods to internal methods
      this.control.openDialog = this.internalOpenDialog.bind(this);
      this.control.closeDialog = this.internalCloseDialog;
    }
  }

  internalOpenDialog(): Observable<boolean> {
    // ...
  }

  internalCloseDialog(result: boolean) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

```js
export class MyHostComponent {
   controlObject= {};
}
```

```
<my-component-to-control [control]="controlObject"></my-component-to-control>

<a (click)="controlObject.open()">Call open method</a>
```

Comment: very clean approach

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation when using the callback 'eventClick' of the [fullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) library, whose callbacks are returning from outside the angular zone, causing my application to have partial and unreliable effects.  I was able to combine the zone approach and a closure reference to the component as seen below in order to raise an output event.  Once I started executing the event inside of the zone.run() method the event and it's effects were once again predictable and picked up by angular change detection.  Hope this helps someone.

```
constructor(public zone: NgZone) { // code removed for clarity
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.configureCalendar();
}

private configureCalendar() {
    // FullCalendar settings
    this.uiConfig = {
        calendar: { // code removed for clarity

        }
    };

    this.uiConfig.calendar.eventClick = this.onEventClick();

}

private onEventClick() {
    const vm = this;

    return function (event, element, view) {
        vm.zone.run(() => {
            vm.onSequenceSelected.emit(event.sequenceSource);                    
        });

        return false;

    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to [@Dave Kennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39280942/1904479):

> Calling the function from the console is now as simple as:
>
> `my.namespace.publicFunc()`

**1)** If we try to access our component's public method from a different domain you will get caught into CORS issue (the cross origin problem, can be solved if both server and client code resides in same machine).

**2)** if you were to call this method from server using javascript, you will have to use `window.opener.my.namespace.publicFunc()` instead of `window.my.namespace.publicFunc():`

`window.opener.my.namespace.publicFunc();`

Comment: what is `my`? Is that the literal value? Or some special key?

Comment: Any variable name you can choose instead of my ""ngOnInit() {
    window.my = window.my || {};
    window.my.namespace = window.my.namespace || {};
    window.my.namespace.publicFunc = this.publicFunc.bind(this);
  }
""