# Angular2 - using child component as value of an attribute

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to show a popover as the user clicks on the input field which works fine but I want the data-content attribute of that popover be coming from the template of a child component. Here is an example:

**parent.ts**

```
import {Component,AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ChildComponent} from './child_test.ts';


@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<input type='text' data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="bottom" [attr.data-content]="getPopoverContent()" />`,
    providers: [ChildComponent]
})
class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
    constructor(private _child: ChildComponent) {}

    getPopoverContent(){
        return this._child; //returning empty object instead of child template
    }
    ngAfterViewInit(){
        $("input").popover();
    }

}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

**child.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: "child-component",
    template: "<div>Popover content from child.</div>"
})
export class ChildComponent{};
```

Should I use DynamicComponentLoader instead of dependency injection? if so then how can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you have the Component in providers? It should be on directives and you should query for it, not inject it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround:

Assign the a temporary variable to the component you want to display

```
<transaction-filter #popoverComponent></transaction-filter>
```

Important: The component above must expose an ElementRef in its definition

```
constructor(public el: ElementRef) {}
```

Create the element that will show the popover

```
<button class="btn-sm btn-link text-muted"
    data-animation="true"
    data-placement="bottom"
    title="Create Rule"
    [popover]="popoverComponent">

    Create Rule...
</button>
```

Now the popover directive itself:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/tsd.d.ts"/>

import 'bootstrap'

import { Directive, ElementRef, Input} from 'angular2/core'

declare var $: JQueryStatic;

@Directive({
    selector: '[popover]',
})
export class PopoverDirective {
    @Input('popover') _component: any
    _popover: JQuery

    constructor(private _el: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // Hide the component
        this._component.el.nativeElement.style.display = "none"

        // Attach it to the content option
        this._popover = $(this._el.nativeElement)
            .popover({
            html: true,
            content: this._component.el.nativeElement
        })

        // When the below event fires, the component will be made visible and will remain
        this._popover.on('shown.bs.popover', () => {
            this._component.el.nativeElement.style.display = "block"
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One problem is that binding to an attribute stringifies the value

```
 [attr.data-content]
```

therefore this approach won't work.

It seems the Bootstrap popover expects a string, therefore this would be fine but stringifying an Angular component won't you give it's HTML.

Comment: So you're saying that there is no way you can bind the value of an attribute to some child template?

Comment: You'd need to add the component to the DOM and then read it's inner/outer-HTML in `ngAfterViewInit()`. That doesn't seem to be a proper solution.

Comment: Why does it need to be a component. If you'd pass the HTML as string in the first place it would work out of the box.

Comment: There might be a way to get the template string from the component instance but you can't expect any Angular bindings in it to work from HTML added this way.

Comment: It needs to be a component because I want to give some input to it and use the resulting template as value of data-bnding attribute.

Comment: I got it, but then you can't use an attribute to pass it. I don't know the Bootstrap popover well enough to tell if there are other ways to pass content.

Comment: There is one other way we can pass content to the popover by using jquery as follows
`$("input").popover({
 content: "I want resulting child template here."
})`

Comment: If it needs a string here it still won't work with Angular binding. If you want to add an Angular component dynamically you have to use `DynamicComponentLoader`. You need a position from Bootstrap for DCL where to add the component.

Comment: Is there any way to bind an angular2 function to the native event for example what if I want to do this
`$("input").popover({ content: "<a href='#' onclick='someFunc()' "})>callFunc</a>`
where someFunc() is defined in the parent component.

Comment: You would need the popover to be shown, then you can query the `<a href...`  and then you can add an event listener. You could use native JS the way you showed in your last comment to call some global function that calls back to Angular like shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296704/angular2-how-to-call-component-function-from-outside-the-app/35297044#35297044.

Comment: But I don't want to pollute the global namespace by defining a function globally. Isn't there any way to call the function of parent component using native event?

Comment: An event might work. `@HostBinding('some-event', [$event] ) myEventHandler(event) {...} ` or `@HostBinding('window:some-event', [$event] ) myEventHandler(event) {...} ` in case the popover content is added somewhere to `body`. I'm not sure if the syntax about is correct (just from my memory, I'm on my phone)