# Communication between Angular2 and Flex

Tags: apache-flex, angular

How can I do to make a communication between flex (swf) application and angular2 application?

I know how to do with js and flex but I don't see how flex can find a angular2 method.

With JS : just need method like :

```
function flexUp() {
    console.log('Flex Up');
}
```

and in flex, call the JS method :

```
ExternalInterface.call("flexUp");
```

I'm newbie in the JS/Angular2 world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fire events in flex and listen to them in Angular [Angular 2 - communication of typescript functions with external js libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997625/angular-2-communication-of-typescript-functions-with-external-js-libraries/36997723#36997723)

or make methods from Angular components, directives, or services globally known like explained in [Angular2 - how to call component function from outside the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296704/angular2-how-to-call-component-function-from-outside-the-app)

Comment: Thanks. It's helpfull!!

Answer (score 0):

The good code :

In flex :

```
ExternalInterface.call("window.angularFlexComponent.initFlex");
```

In Angular2 :

- In flex.d.ts :

```
interface Window {
    angularFlexComponent: any;
}
```

- In flex.components.ts :

```
import {Component, NgZone, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'flex',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/flex/flex.html'
})
export class FlexComponent implements OnDestroy {
    constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone) {
        window.angularFlexComponent = { initFlex: this.initFlex.bind(this), zone: _ngZone };
    }
    initFlex(): void {
        console.log('Artemis Flex Up');
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        window.angularFlexComponent = null;
    }
}
```