# How best to handle large external API so that a single instance can be shared among multiple components?

Tags: typescript, angular, webrtc

I want to create a single instance of an object with a [large external API](http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/), and share it among several components of my app.

This API has several event methods (e.g. `onJoin()`, `onClose()`, `onOpen()`, etc.) which I need to implement. As different events are associated with different components of my app, I was thinking of implementing these events within those components, rather than all within a Singleton class.

Alternatively, I was wondering if I should--or even could--have each of these event methods trigger a custom event created with `EventEmitter`, and have listener methods in each of the relevant component classes ready to handle these events. But it appears that `EventEmitter` [can only be used by components and directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html), not plain classes.

Another concern is whether I should create a Singleton class for this object or treat it as a kind of 'Service' and inject it into the dependent components.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I would recommended a `Service` in order to make the network calls, also it's good for caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using EventEmitter, which after some trial and error I discovered didn't work (the event callback function were getting called late, or not at all), I implemented the callback functions within the external library. These initial functions use window.dispatchEvent(event) to emit a CustomEvent, passing into it their original 'event' parameter. This event can then be picked up inside my app using @HostListener('window:onWhatever', ['$event']).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997625/angular-2-communication-of-typescript-functions-with-external-js-libraries) is where I got this solution from.

I also used a Service to handle initializing the external library object and encapsulate its functions and options. This approach seems to be working well.