# Call angular 2 function from javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, angular

I need to call a angular 2 function from javascript.

```
export class myClass
{
   imageSelected : boolean;


   javascriptFunction()
   {
       this.imageSelected = true // DOESN'T CHANGE IMAGESELECTED STATE...IT'S AN ANGULAR VARIABLE

       //CALL ANGULAR FUNCTION HERE TO CHANGE VARIABLE 
   }

    angular2Function()
    {
        this.imageSelected = true
    }
}
```

How I can call angular2Function inside javascriptFunction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997625/angular-2-communication-of-typescript-functions-with-external-js-libraries/36997723#36997723

Comment: How I can call this event ?

Comment: What event? Call how? Please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: In my javascript2Function how can I call "updateNotes($event)" ?

Comment: Have you checked my answer from the link and also the link at the end of the answer? I can't see `updateNotes($event)` in your question.