# Angular2 Router link from sanitized HTML

Tags: angular

I'm displaying sanitized HTML in one my routes, which contains links to other parts of the router. However, clicking them results in the website reloading.

How do I pass the link to the router from outside the angular2 scope?

Example

**article.component.ts**

```
  @Component({
      selector: "article",
      template: `<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>`, //html is not parsed by ng because its outside the scope
      providers: []
  })

  export class ArticleComponent{
    public content;
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){
        this.content = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<a href="/article/some_id">example link</a>`); 
    }

  }
```

In my case, this.content is dynamic html downloaded via http request, which is why it must be sanitized.

**app.routing.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "article/:id",
        component: ArticleComponent
    }
]

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: I added some example code. It's just [innerHTML]="sanitizedHTML", where sanitizedHTML contains regular href links (since [routerLinks] aren't parsed). Clicking them reloads the page rather than sending it through the router. I'm looking for a neat way to force the router to handle those links.

Comment: You can only add plain HTML using `[innerHTML]`. No bindings, no directives, no components, and no anything else Angular2 specific.

Comment: Yes. I want to try to access the router from outside the ng scope, or maybe some recommendations of a better way to do this.

Comment: "access the router from outside ng scope" is quite vague. Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997625/angular-2-communication-of-typescript-functions-with-external-js-libraries/36997723#36997723

Comment: I mean I'd like to attach click handlers to those links (from outside angular), that will pass those links/click events to the angular component that contains the sanitizedHTML. So that I can use this.router.navigate instead of letting the website reload. That looks useful. Thanks.