# Angular2 Calling exposed method from outside app and loses change binding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, angular2-changedetection

I have a public method that I exposed to `window`. This method talks to a `Component` and modifies a variable I am watching in my template. But when I change the value, the `*ngIf()` does not get triggered.

app.component

```
constructor(private _public: PublicService,) {
        window.angular = {methods: this._public};
    }
```

PublicService

```
export class PublicService {

    constructor(
        private  _viewManager: ViewManagerComponent,
    ) {}

    CallMe(){
        this._viewManager.renderView('page1')
    }
}
```

LayoutManagerComponent

```
@Component({
    selector: 'view-manager',
    template: `<page *ngIf="view == 'page1'"></page>`
})
export class ViewManagerComponent {
    //This is the variable being watched
    view = "page";

    renderView = function(type){
        console.log(type)
        this.view = type;
        console.log(this.view)
    };
}
```

So the idea is that when the view initially loads, the view is blank. Then when I type `angular.methods.CallMe()` it modifies the `view` variable to `page1` which should then show the html for the Component. If I console `renderView` function it is successfully getting called, just the view does not change.

----Update - Still not working -------

```
export class ViewManagerComponent {
    constructor(private zone:NgZone,private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {

    }
    view = "page";

     @Output() renderView(type){
        // type is 'page'
        console.log(this.view)
        this.zone.run(() => {
            // type is 'page'
            console.log(this.view)
            this.view = type;
            // type is 'page1'
            console.log(this.view)
        });
        // type is 'page1'
        console.log(this.view)
        //cdRef errors: 
        //view-manager.component.ts:36 Uncaught TypeError: this.cdRef.detectChanges is not a function(…)
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    };

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case Angular2 doesn't know that it needs to run change detection because the change is caused by code that runs outside Angulars zone.

Run change detection explicitely

```
contructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

someMethodCalledFromOutside() {
  // code that changes properties in this component 
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Run the code that modifies the components properties inside Angulars zone explicitely

```
contructor(private zone:NgZone) {}

someMethodCalledFromOutside() {
  this.zone.run(() => {
  // code that changes properties in this component 
  });
}
```

The `zone` method is a better fit when `// code that changes properties in this component` not only changes properties of the current component, but also causes changes to other components (like `this.router.navigate()`, call method references of methods of other components) because `zone.run()` executes the code inside Angulars zone, and you don't need to explicitely take care of change detection in every component where a change might happen because of this call.

If you use `function(...)` instead of `() =>` it's likely you'll get unexpected behavior with `this` in code inside the Angular component.

See also my answer to this similar question for more details [Angular 2 - communication of typescript functions with external js libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997625/angular-2-communication-of-typescript-functions-with-external-js-libraries/36997723#36997723)

**update**

```
export class ViewManagerComponent {
    constructor(private zone:NgZone,private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {
      self = this;
    }
    view = "page";

     @Output() renderView(type){
        // type is 'page'
        console.log(self.view)
        self.zone.run(() => {
            // type is 'page'
            console.log(self.view)
            self.view = type;
            // type is 'page1'
            console.log(self.view)
        });
        // type is 'page1'
        console.log(self.view)
        self.cdRef.detectChanges();
    };

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes and first tried `this.zone.run` but it didnt work(no errors). I then tried the `cfRef.detectChanges()` and first complained about it not being a provider. I added to `app.module`, then got this error: `view-manager.component.ts:30 Uncaught TypeError: this.cdRef.detectChanges is not a function(…)`

Comment: It's probably because of `this` not pointing to your current component instance as mentioned in my answer.  The answer I linked to should provide a solution for that

Comment: I modified my code. Please see above. I placed several consoles before and after to track and `this` seems to be scoped correctly.

Comment: Why don't you just change  `@Output() renderView = function(type){` to `@Output() renderView(type){`?

Comment: Please add the error message to your question if you get one.

Comment: changed render view format and added error in code comment when I uncomment `this.cdRef.detectChanges();`

Comment: That worked! Can you tell me why so i can look out for issues like this?

Comment: If you pass `this.renderView`then `this` inside `renderView()` doesn't point to the `ViewManagerComponent` but to the context where it is actually called from (a nice JS feature ;-) ). You can use `window.xxx = this.renderView.bind(this);` or `window.xxx = (type) => this.renderView(type);` or the way I showed above. Your `console.log()`s seemed to work but I assume that the values were just set from previous calls in the context `this` was pointing to.