# Angular 12 and update ngModel from window method

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webview

I am making an Angular 12 application, and I need change ngModel value via global/window method. (Because Android Webview can call from kotlin only public javascripts methods)

I'm tried use bind, and angular service. Method is called correctly, but **ngModel** not changed - input not filled.

> Via **bind**, see on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/global-method-01?file=src/app/app.component.ts), or via **service**, see on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/global-method-02?file=src/app/app.component.ts) too.

Unfortunately, the input is not filled in in any case. You can try on Stackblitz, via browser console.

So I need to update the ngModel value, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fire a custom event as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997625/angular-2-communication-of-typescript-functions-with-external-js-libraries/36997723#36997723)

I've updated your code to use custom event here [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/global-method-01-bv41bs?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

From console tab,

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('custom-event'));
```