# Routing from html DOM to Component directly

Tags: angular

Trying to route from html´s template to a component, I tried different approaches, but they are not working.

I can route between component, from html to a template or urlTemplate (setting it value in script´s tag). But I can´t link from a html to a component.

Here is the idea:

**index.html**

```ts
<a href="my_angular_component">My_something</a>
```

**my_component.ts**

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'myComponent-list',
  template: `
    <h2>myComponents</h2>

    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let myComponent of myComponents">
        {{myComponent.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
```

I tried the next approaches:

Using routes´s component and [routerLink] attribute:

**routes.ts**

```ts
export const MyComponentAppRoutes = [
  { path: 'myComponent', component: my_component },
]
```

**index.html**

```ts
<a [routerLink]="['/myComponent']">My_something</a>
```

*Not working, because I can´t use routerLink in html, directly.*

Another one, definying route provider directly from html by script:

```ts
<script>
        var app = angular.module("HelloWorld", ["ngRoute"]);
        app.config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when("/cartelera", {
-- HOW CAN CALL MY COMPONENT HERE? NOT TEMPLATE DIRECTLY BECAUSE I WANT TO INJECT A SERVICE.
-- NOT A URLTEMPLATE FOR THE SAME REASON.
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Finally, I defined a component called mylink, Just for using routeLink from the definition of itself, but, event it works, doesnt look correct. Have I to define a component for every link I have?

I can´t get it. :S

Thanks mates... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. When this code is executed, Angular is not yet running.

You can assign a value to `window.someName` and then from within the component read `window.someName`.

If actually `function($routeProvider) { ... }` is called after Angular and your component is initialized, you can assign a method of your component to `window.someName` and than from your script tag call `window.someName(someParam)`

See also [Angular2 - how to call component function from outside the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296704/angular2-how-to-call-component-function-from-outside-the-app/35297044#35297044)

Another approach would be an event

From your script method

```ts
var event = new Event('my-event');
// or
var event = new CustomEvent('my-event', {'detail': someData});
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

and in your Angular component

```ts
@HostListener('window:my-event', ['$event'])
myEventHandler(event) {
  console.log(event);
  // or
  console.log(event.detail);
}
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: Mmmm... Thanks @Günter Zöchbauer. So, What approach do you recommend me for achieving this functionality?

Comment: If you are sure Angular is running already and the component initialized, when the function is called, I'd use the event approach I just added.

Comment: Thanks again. I am gonna try it and I will let you know. And I accept the question as well. Cheers mate... :)

Comment: I added a few more details

Comment: Got it. Thanks Günter. I did a small demo and it works... I need to implement in the whole project from your idea... Cool mate :)