# Angular2 - call component function from outside the app with service call inside

Tags: angular, typescript, components

With this reference: [Angular2 - how to call component function from outside the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296704/angular2-how-to-call-component-function-from-outside-the-app/35297044)

I tried to call function outside my component.
Function which I call has service call:

```
 private updateContact(contact) {
      this._myService.updateClientContacts(contact).subscribe(updateData => this._myService.getClientContacts());
    }
```

I tried call it doing this:

```
dataSourceOptions.transport = {
      read: function(e){
             e.success(griddata);
      },
      update: function (e) {
        // locate item in original datasource and update it
        griddata[getIndexById(e.data.ContactID)] = e.data;
        window['clientComponentRef'].zone.run(() => {window['clientComponentRef'].component.updateContact(griddata[getIndexById(e.data.ContactID)]).bind(this);});
        //on success
        e.success();
        // on failure
        //e.error("XHR response", "status code", "error message");
      }
```

I also try it without .bind(this) on this line of code:

```
 window['clientComponentRef'].zone.run(() => {window['clientComponentRef'].component.updateContact(griddata[getIndexById(e.data.ContactID)]).bind(this);});
```

but it didn't help.

but it returns error 405, and I cant access to myService and post edited item. Does anyone have idea how to solve that?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think `405` is related to call from outside?

Comment: 405 - Method Not Allowed is error from myService.handleError.

Comment: I'm sure this is an error produced by an HTTP server.

Comment: You are right! It was error produced by http server, I solve it :)

Comment: Glad to hear :D