# Make function usable outside class in angular2

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to use a function in one of my classes in a third party library(highcharts) I included in my project.

Something along the lines of:

```
export class TrendPage {
  ...
  functionToUse(){
    this.top = someCalculation();
  }
  ...
  this.chart = Highcharts.chart(this.chartContainer, {
    ...
        xAxis: {
            events: {
                afterSetExtremes: ()=> {
                   this.functionToUse()
                }
            }
        },
   ...
```

Is there a correct way to do this?

Solution I found:

Using ngZone to run the function outside the scope of the zone as in this answer [Angular2 - how to call component function from outside the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296704/angular2-how-to-call-component-function-from-outside-the-app/35297044#35297044)

Comment: I don’t know what you want can you provide concrete example of what you trying to do and expected output? Also if the code isn’t working provide stack trace

Comment: I am trying to change the member value "top" in the class TrendPage. Since I am trying to use "this.functionToUse()", the context "this" is in is the context of the chart, not the component.

Comment: I have found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35297044/5774939 
Wondering if there is a better/alternative way to achieve this

Comment: Also use ` afterSetExtremes: (event) => {` instead of `afterSetExtremes: function (event) {` otherwise `this` won't eork as expected inside the function. (search for arrow functions for more details)

Answer (score 0):

In

```
this.functionToUse()
```

"this" is inside the scope of the function and cannot "see" for function outside. Can you try this code instead?

```
afterSetExtremes: ()=>
{
    this.functionToUse()
}
```

Be carefull because "event" variable cannot be used anymore using this anonymous function. (search more for lambda/anonymous function)

Comment: Ahh yes the code I wrote above actually follows this convention (I was testing other things) will edit my original post.