# Append html to div javascript and bind typescript function to a (click) event not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have an external javascript file and I have a function that appends HTML to siteLayoutComponent.html DIV as below code:

```
function LoadNotificationData(data) {
        $("#lstNotification").append(' <li id="' + data.id + '"><a (click)="logout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw" "></i>' + data.subject + '</a></li> <li id="dv' + data.id + '" class="divider"></li>')     
}
```

logout function that in a siteLayoutComponent.ts

```
logout() {    
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

after inspecting the generated code, we could realize that the event wasn't rendered in a correct way, I need to perform this binding dynamically in the appended HTML. any Ideas

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296704/angular2-how-to-call-component-function-from-outside-the-app

Comment: Why are you dynamically appending that `<li>` in the first place? It should always exist, and be hidden if supposed to be hidden.

Comment: "after inspecting the generated code, we could realize that the event wasn't rendered in a correct way". How was it rendered and why was this wrong?

Comment: Side note: personally I avoid mixing HTML with Javascript.
If I had to write this in jQuery, I would use something like `$li.append($("<a>").click(logout));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to use angular2 directives instead of jquery append because that is the proper way to work in angular2 like:

// maybe json list or lists
this.data = [{id:1212,subject:"login"},{id:1212,subject:"logout"}];

you can push pop your data from this variable and on behalf of this data variable, you can create your list like given in screenshot attached.
[image]

Thanks