# how to add dialog box in with yes or no option and call function based on that

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am new to typescript/angular  project and working on one project. In .html file i am calling delete operation but i want to add extra confirmation for delete operation. My existing code is :

```
<a (click)="onUserDelete()" class = "btn btn-danger" >Delete User</a>
```

How to add conditional check and call **'onUserDelete()'** function whic is define in .ts file.

I tried adding  but it always throws error.
Tried code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function UserDelete(){
            onUserDelete();
        }
    </script>
    <a (click)="UserDelete()" class = "btn btn-danger" >Delete</a>
```

It always throws UserDelete is **not a function.**

Comment: You get this error from the TypeScript compiler, which doesn't know you have function named `UserDelete()` (beacuse it defined in JS). But why you cannot add the condition in the function `onUserDelete()`?

Comment: Are you sure you are asking about the *AngularJS* (i.e. verson 1.x) and not the *Angular* (i.e. version 2-6)? `(click)` seems more like an Angular syntax than AngularJS. Also, what libraries are you using for the UI?

Comment: if it is in another ts file wouldn't you need to import it into your component?

Answer (score 0):

Make your ts file function for global access and then use it with

`window.angularComponentRef.zone.run(function () { 
       window.angularComponentRef.componentFn(10)
 })`

Use NgZone for accessing function from outside.
For more info you can follow: [Angular2 - how to call component function from outside the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296704/angular2-how-to-call-component-function-from-outside-the-app/35312658)