# Web MediaAPI - MediaRecorder : Adding AddEventListener with handler in parent class scope instead of inline callback

Tags: angular, typescript, asynccallback, web-mediarecorder

In my angular project, I have a class with 2 member functions. Inside first function, I have 2 levels of callbacks. Inside the first callback , I need to add 2nd level of event callback. Inside this 2nd level callback, I need to be able to call the 2nd member function of the top-level class. I tried hacks suggested in https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/javascript-callbacks-variable-scope-problem. It did not work for me. Currently I am trying [Angular2 - how to call component function from outside the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296704/angular2-how-to-call-component-function-from-outside-the-app/39280942) which talks about ngZone to expose component member function.

Details of my code:

I have an audio processing "AudioProcessingUtility" class written in Angular 8. In its Init() I am initializing MediaRecorder. I am adding a listener for "datavailable" event. This listener function needs to call my utility function from "master" class. i.e. it has to go to the scope of the parent class, from the callback.

Code:

```
 export class AudioProcessingUtility  {
//integrated componet-level properties

//video conf specific properties
localAudioStreamStdObj: MediaStream;
mediaRecorder: any;
agoraService: any;
localStream: Stream; 

constructor() {}

private StreamInit() { //top-level member function to init

    this.localStream.init(() => { 

        this.agoraService.client.publish(this.localStream, function (err) { //This triggers "stream-published" event.
            console.log("Publish local stream error: " + err);
        });
        this.agoraService.client.on('stream-published', function (evt) {
            console.log("Publish local stream successfully");
            this.localAudioStreamStdObj = new MediaStream([evt.stream.getAudioTrack()]); //Specific details of media API
            this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(this.localAudioStreamStdObj, { mimeType: 'audio/webm' }); //Specific details of media API
            this.mediaRecorder.start(4000);
            this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => { //Triggered every 4 seconds. 
                console.log("callbackfn: data vailable");
                console.log(event.data);
                //MY NEED
                this.audioProcessorCallback(event.data); //top-level member function be called
            }); 

            this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
            });
            ////end real time grab

        });
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("failed", err);
        });

}//end of stream Init function

public audioProcessorCallback(eventdatavailable) { //Top-level function to be called from 2nd-level callback
    console.log("My processing");
    //Do REST API calls. Based on internal states of the class, do specific processing
  }
 } //end of AudioProcessingUtility
```

The problem:

The dataavailable event is fired. But I get error in the following lines. It gives error **ERROR TypeError: this.audioProcessorCallback is not a function**

```
     //MY NEED
     this.audioProcessorCallback(event.data); //top-level member function be called is not recognized.
```

I understood that this is because - inside the callback, it is not able to find the 'this context'. Please suggest how I could call my class function instead of having to put everything in the inline callback function, which is not practical for me.

EDIT: I rewrote the question to provide show full code and changed the description. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be using an arrow function since the `this` in the function doesn’t refer to the lexical `this`. Also it is unclear why you’re returning in the callback: it doesn’t do anything.

Comment: I thought I created arrow function. I just edited to add );.  My callback is working. But as you mentioned, this does not refer to 'this'. How to make it make it refer  to this? Or to call a class member? I read an article  https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/javascript-callbacks-variable-scope-problem which indicated that return would give the previous context and calls. But it looks like it is not doing anything, as you mentioned. Please suggest the best way to use the class member.

Comment: What’re you trying to do, when returning the function?

Comment: I'm trying to 'pop' the 'outer class context'. As per the article, it gets me the "outer context" i.e. the context of my utility class which has some REST API calls enclosed within a class member. I intend to call that function when event "datavailable" is trigger. I can not copy all of that code into callback since I have few fags and other details enclosed in the class.

Comment: Why can’t you call a method that’s in the class? It’s still not clear to me. And this sounds more like an XY problem.

Comment: Sorry about missing some detail in original question. I have another level of callback. I initiate stream. Then I get callback once stream is published. Inside that callback, I need to call the processing function from the class. This is not accessible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204859/discussion-between-ishwara-bhat-and-terry).

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why you'll need a `return` in the callback. Consider this:

```js
client.on("stream-published", evt => {
  console.log("Publish local stream successfully");
  this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
    console.log("callbackfn: data vailable");
    console.log("Calling this.audioprocessor(event)");
    this.audioprocessor(event);
  });
});
```

Once the `callback` is fired, it will trigger the `this.audioprocessor`. Since you're using an arrow function, the context of `this` will be the `class`

Comment: I missed adding another level of callback in the question. I have updated the question now. i.e. inside the callback, I register callback, which needs to call the function of the class.

Comment: > this.audioprocessor .. is this a method on you class?

Comment: Yes. It is the public method in the class.

Comment: > this.mediaRecorder is this a method on the class also?

Comment: Yes. It is a method on the class. I edited my original description to reflect his better. Thanks.

Comment: For context .. posting your full code will be clearer than the description

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204875/discussion-between-ishwara-bhat-and-c-ogoo).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was due to context. From the callback of 2nd level, it was not able to see 'this context' and the member functions were not accessible. I exposed the Angular component through ngZone. I'm calling it from my callback as if I'm calling from external javascript function. The answer is based on  [Angular2 - how to call component function from outside the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296704/angular2-how-to-call-component-function-from-outside-the-app/39280942)

```
//Mycomponent.ts

import {  NgZone, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

constructor(
        //other params removed for clarity
      private _ngZone: NgZone
      )
      {
      //This is how I register with 'window'. 'audioProcessFn' is the alias for my member function.
       window['MycomponentRef'] = { component: this, zone: _ngZone, audioProcessFn: (value) => this.audioprocessor(value) };
      }

 ngOnDestroy() 
{
    window['MycomponentRef'] = null;
}
```

Inside my callback , in place of

```
      //MY NEED
            this.audioProcessorCallback(event.data); //top-level member function be called
        });
```

I have this code now -

```
   /MY NEED
                    window['MycomponentRef'].zone.run(() => {
                        console.log("ngZone.run . Call getRealtime Emotion ");
                        window['MycomponentRef'].audioProcessFn(base64data );
                    })          
                }

            });
```