# How can I call a javascript function in a website with selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, selenium

So this is an element in a website

```
<span class="log-out-ico" ng-click="logout()">/
```

Let's say I don't want to click it, instead I just want to run the "logout()" script from selenium,
Is it even possible? If so how?!

This is what I tried

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("logout()");
```

But I get this error :

```
javascript error: logout is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

**Eg page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p>Click the button to run a function:</p>
  <button ng-click="myFunc()">OK</button>
  <p>The button has been clicked {{count}} times.</p>
</div>

<script>
a=function(){
console.log("hiii")
}
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.myFunc = function() {
      $scope.count++;
    };
  }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see that the muFunc is not inside the script block but inside the Angular controller . You cannot call it directl.

But the function 'a' is normal javascript function so you call it directly .

call a and open browser console , you can see "hiiii" printed

THere are ways to expose angular function outside f the angular module but its not straight forward

[Angular2 - how to call component function from outside the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296704/angular2-how-to-call-component-function-from-outside-the-app)