# How to call a function from imported module in angular 2 (typescript)

Tags: typescript, angular

```
abc.component.ts
import...
...
...
@component({ ... })

export class Abc {

  public foo(){
     console.log("execute foo in UserComponent's xyz() ");
  }
}

user.component.ts
import...
...
...
import {Abc} from '../utils/abc.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'user',
    templateUrl: 'app/user/user.html',
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    directives: [Abc]
})
export class UserComponent {

   xyz(){
      Abc.foo(); //--> ?
   }
}
```

I have imported Abc module in user.component.ts. How can I call Abc.foo() in UserComponent Class methods?

Comment: How are the components related in the DOM. You usually don't call a method of a class. You usually want to call a method on a specific instance.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer In DOM 'abc'(html element) will be there inside 'user' (html element)

Comment: Please add some code/html to your question that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have added typescript code please check. My requirement is to call the method of imported module.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276291/how-do-expose-angular-2-methods-publicly/35276652?noredirect=1#comment58266532_35276652

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Parent calls a ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child) scenario from official documentation Angula2 like this

*Parent component*

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <abc></abc>
    </div>`
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild(ABC)
  private abc:ABC;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.abc.foo();
  }
}
```

Corresponding plunker example is here  https://plnkr.co/edit/VPsMTtJ29XBWr7SCqbzA?p=preview

Comment: `'directives' does not exist in type 'Component'` I get this msg when I tried ur solution.