# How to call a function in angular2 component from a jquery button click?

Tags: jquery, angular

I have a single page application which is developed in MVC and jQuery. I have a button in my cshtml page and click of that button, I need to load a function which is present inside angular component. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Following Dynamic Component concept?

Comment: can you add your componet and html

Comment: Robert and k11k2, I had a requirement to open angular component in a dialog on click of a button in jquery application. I am able to achieve this using iframe. I will post the code shortly.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible ways out is to put your component in global scope, i.e. create your component and put it on window object. Here is a thread which achieves the similar functionality

[How do expose angular 2 methods publicly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276291/how-do-expose-angular-2-methods-publicly)

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Usman. I am able to call the function by following the link you gave. I had a requirement to open angular component in a dialog on click of a button in jquery application. I am able to achieve this using iframe.

Answer (score -1):

I am able to open angular2 app inside a jquery dialog by the below approach:

jQuery app:

1) Inside the function where I am opening a dialog, I am creating an iframe and then passing the angular app URL as its source.

2) I am also declaring a window level variable and assigning it with data from my parent jQuery app so that I can make use of this data in my child angular application.

```
window.angAppInput = "Input to angular app"
```

Angular app:

1)Before component declaration, I declare window object as below:

```
declare var window: any;
```

2)Inside ngOnInit, I am initializing my angular application with data from parent jQuery app using below:

```
this.angAppInput = window.parent.angAppInput;
```