# Call Angular 5 function from Android WebView

Tags: android, typescript, android-webview, angular5

I am trying to call Angular 5 function from my Abdroid WebView.

**In Android**

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
this.mWebView.evaluateJavascript("fooBar();", null);
} else {
this.mWebView.loadUrl("fooBar();");
}
```

In my Angular component I have added fooBar function

**In Angular Component**

```
fooBar=function(){
console.log("fooBar");
}
```

But above code throws

**Error**

```
VM772:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: fooBar is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Could anyone help me on How to call Typescript function from Android `Webview`

Comment: Found the solution for this?

Comment: @DroidDev no sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How do expose angular 2 methods publicly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276291/how-to-expose-angular-2-methods-publicly/35276652#35276652)

I don't know why you would do this, in your android webview. Maybe reevaluate that decision, tho I don't know the specifics.
(would comment but can't)

Comment: I need to return value to Angular 5 from webview