# Angular 6 - call Angular function from external js file

Tags: javascript, angular

Recently I'm rewriting a plan JS app with Angular 6.

The old stuff work like this:

file js inside a iframe that call "parent.update_track()" function defined into main.js file into iframe container.

that's not work in Angular when app run on production, the response is: TypeError: parent.update_track is not a function.

so how can I call this function "update_track()" declared into a ts file in a component from an external js file contained into iFrame?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: of course this should be the answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276291/how-to-expose-angular-2-methods-publicly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276291/how-to-expose-angular-2-methods-publicly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use post message functionality.

So in your iframe you can just call the opener window (the parent) to post message, for more info you can use [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Then in the angular app (the parent) you can use the following listener:

```
@HostListener('window:message',['$event'])
onMessage(e) {
  if (e.origin!="http://localhost:4200") {
     return false;
  }

  alert('here i am');
}
```

}

Note:  you should change the e.origin test to support both local env and production.