# Return value and get it from window.angularComponentRef.zone.run

Tags: angular

I know that how to call angular functions inside the component via a static file according to the below link :

[How to expose angular 2 methods publicly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276291/how-to-expose-angular-2-methods-publicly/35276652)

It says use zone in angular as I mention below :

```
 window.angularComponentRef.zone.run(() => {
 window.angularComponentRef.component.calledFromOutsideToUploadChatImageandGetURL("test");
})
```

my angular function is :

```
calledFromOutsideToUploadChatImageandGetURL(chatImage64Bit: string) {
    this.doctorService.UploadChatImageandGetURL(chatImage64Bit).subscribe(
        data => {

            console.log(chatImage64Bit);
            //blablabla


    );

    return "RESULT";
}
```

But I want to get returned value `("RESULT")` from my angular `function(calledFromOutsideToUploadChatImageandGetURL)` but I cant. I just could call it! any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit tries I found out it could be done simply by the following code:

```
 var retuenValue = window.angularComponentRef.zone.run(function map() {
 var  xx =  window.angularComponentRef.component.calledFromOutsideToUploadChatImageandGetURL("test");
                return xx;
            });
 console.log(retuenValue);
```