# How can i call angular/typescript function from AIML? if not possible, how can i make Javascript function call angular/typescript function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, aiml

I am trying to make the **AIML template** to call the **submitButton()** function from **file.component.ts**, however **AIML is an XML based markup language** therefore it wont accept angular syntax such as **(click)**. Because of this, i tried using **onclick** to call a javascript function first then try to call submitButton() from there. However I don't know how to do this.

I also made some changes backend to try calling angular directly by replacing some of the response.output with angular syntax hoping it would work. but it doesn't..

I am trying to call the function from angular/typescript using a JavaScript function. How can i do this?

AIML (response.output)

```
<template>Select an option 
    <button id="image1" onclick="triggerFunctionInJSFile()" type="submit"> 
      <img height="200" ngmodel="chatMessageModel.input" src="https://scene7.zumiez.com/is/image/zumiez/pdp_hero/adidas-Trefoil-White-%26-Black-T-Shirt-_289236-front-US.jpg" width="200"/> Image 1
    </button>  
    <button id="image2" onclick="triggerFunctionInJSFile()" type="submit"> 
      <img height="200" ngmodel="chatMessageModel.input" src="https://scene7.zumiez.com/is/image/zumiez/pdp_hero/adidas-Trefoil-White-%26-Black-T-Shirt-_289236-front-US.jpg" width="200"/> Image 2
    </button> 
  </template>
```

AIML (request.input)

```
  <pattern>img options</pattern>
```

BackendChanges.java

```
if(respMsg.getOutput().contains("onclick") || respMsg.getOutput().contains("ngmodel")) {
    String click = respMsg.getChatBotMsg().getOutput();
    click = click.replaceAll("\\bonclick\\b", "(click)");

    String model = click;
    model = model.replaceAll("\\bngmodel\\b", "[(ngModel)]");

    respMsg.getChatBotMsg().setOutput(model);
}
```

jsfile.js

```
function triggerFunctionInJSFile() {
    //To Do
    console.log("Triggered the function in js file ");

    fileComponent = require('./dir/file.component'); // i tried using require but doesn't work

    fileComponent.submitButton(); // calling the function from file component

}
```

file.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-file',
    templateUrl: './file.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./file.component.scss']
})
export class FileComponent implements OnInit{

   constructor {}

   ngOnInit() {}

   public submitButton() {
       //submit function here
   }
}
```

in jsfile.js, 'require' will cause the function to go undefined. I'v tried some other methods as well but it doesn't seem to work. May I know what is the correct way to do this? I'v never done something like this before and I can't find anything that works.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use angular click that calls your component method. Then this component method calls your javascript method.

```
<button type="button" (click)="componentFunction()" >Check</button>


componentFunction(){
  triggerFunctionInJSFile();
}
```

Note: your js function should be in global scope.

Comment: AIML doesn't recognize angular syntax (click). due to that i need to call js first. do you know how to call angular function into js function?

Comment: Check these: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35297044  or   https://stackoverflow.com/a/35276652

Comment: Thanks @IrshadAli. the window reference actually solve my problem!